# How can I list all constraints of tables in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I list all constraints of tables in MS Access? I can't find out how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
SELECT * FROM MSysRelationships
```

Treat this table as *read-only*. Don't edit it.

Comment: yeah. I ran it and it worked but I can't find constraints such as not null.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has system tables that contain information on each table's
structure. Access does not. Therefore, there are no system tables to query
with Jet SQL. Use the ADO and ADOX libraries, or the DAO library in VBA
instead. Use Tables and Indexes if using ADOX. Use TableDefs, Fields, and
the PrimaryKey Index if using DAO. One must use ADO's OpenSchema function
of the Connection object to retrieve the list of constraints, not DAO,
because it's not available in DAO.

If you just want the column names of a table, that's easy enough with SQL.
Try the following syntax to export the column names to a text file:

```
SELECT * INTO [TEXT;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=F:\Work\Test\].MyTable.txt
FROM MyTable
WHERE (1 = 0);
```